# Create directive to check new message and add badge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, badge, ionic-framework

I use this controller in ionic app to check new message or activity and add a badge if is there news:

```
.controller('checkNew', function($scope, getNewMsg, getNewAct, $localstorage, $cordovaLocalNotification, $http, $state) {
         getNewMsg.getNew(function(data) {if(data!=0){$scope.addActivity(data);$scope.counterAct = data}else{$scope.cancelAllNotification}});
         getNewAct.getNew(function(data) {if(data!=0){$scope.addNotification(data);$scope.counter = data}else{$scope.cancelAllNotification}});
```

and this is for example my .factory getNewMsg:

```
.factory('getNewMsg', function($http, $localstorage, $timeout){
    return {
        getNew: function(callback){
            var user_id = $localstorage.get('user_id');
            var timer;
            function myLoop(){
                timer = $timeout(function(){console.log( "Timeout executed")},5000);
                timer.then(
                    function(){$http.post('http://www.digitalxp.it/appwork/include/check_msg.asp?id='+user_id).success(function(data){callback(data)}).error(function(){alert("Errore di comunicazione!")});myLoop()},
                    function() {console.log("Timer rejected!")}
                    );
            }
            myLoop();
        }}
})
```

my problem is that I've to call the controller each time to add the badge in the header, but I would check only one time and view the badge on all ion-view of the app! (also the side menu near message item!)

I think is it possible with directive, but I dont know how to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated this to use broadcas as you've requested, now your controller will be registered to the event `newMessageReceived` and will update every 5 seconds. Also, this acts more as a service, so I've updated the module to be a service and not a factory.

Please note that I changed `timer.then(setNew, handleError);` to `timer.then(setNew(), handleError);`

```
.controller('checkNew', function($scope, messageService, getNewAct, $localstorage, $cordovaLocalNotification, $http, $state) {
  //register to broadcast and update when the messages are updated
  messageService.newMessageReceived($scope, updateMessage)

  function updateMessage(message) {
    if(message){ 
      $scope.addActivity(message);
      $scope.counterAct = message;
    } else {
      $scope.cancelAllNotification
    }
  }
});

.service('messageService', function($rootScope, $http, $localstorage, $timeout){
  /* Initialization */
  //setup timer to run every 5 seconds
  var timer = $timeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);
  //set the actions for resolve and reject
  timer.then(setNew(), handleError);

  function timeoutFunction() {
    return;
  }

  function handleError() {
    console.log('Timer rejected');
  }
  //every time the newMessageRecieved event is broadcasted, run the callback and register the scope
  function newMessageReceived(scope, callback) {
    callback(getNew());
    scope.$on('newMessageReceived', function() {
      callback(getNew());
    });
  }

  function getNew() {
    return $localstorage && $localstorage.message || undefined;
  }

  function setNew() {
    var user_id = $localstorage.get('user_id');
    return $http.post('http://www.digitalxp.it/appwork/include/check_msg.asp?id='+user_id)
      .success(function(data){
        $localStorage.message = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('newMessageReceived');
      })
      .error(function(){alert("Errore di comunicazione!")})
  }

  return {
    newMessageReceived: newMessageReceived
  };
});
```

Comment: But I've to check if there are new msg about 10 sec loop!

Comment: So i've only to add  <span ng-show=counter class="badge badge-assertive">{{counterAct}}</span> where I would add a badge?

Comment: Yes, although your ng-show would probably be an expression set in updateMessage(), like showBadge or something more intuitive than counter.

Comment: I apply your change. All works fine but only when I start the app! So, for example, if there are new messages, dont update the badge. If I (force) close and reopen the app, the badge was update! it's like the action dont loop!

Comment: I updated a very small spot, please look at the post and see if that change gets you where you need to go.

Comment: I put my controller in side menu view, but I would check if there are new message every 5 sec. So I add console.log("check msg") but in console i see that only one time or when i change view!

Comment: Before your script, I use my .factory in side menu and I see console log every 5 sec correctly fired!

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer then, please? Glad it works for ya!